# Unable to display button or text on video using z-index

Tags: css, html, html5-video

I need to display a play button on video. I tried with z-index. But it seems not working. Below is html code

html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>text</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="test.css">
    </head>
    <body style="overflow: hidden; margin: 0px;">
        <div id="d1">
            <video id="videoID" src="http://clips.vorwaerts-gmbh.de/big_buck_bunny.mp4" type="video/mp4" autoplay>
            <div id="d2">
                <h1 id="h">I am heading</h1>
                <!--<button type="button" id="play-pause" class="play">Play</button>-->
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

CSS:

```
#d1
{
    font-family: 'Avenir', Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
    color: #2c3e50;
    margin-top: 10px;
    width: 55%
}

#videoID
{
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 10;
}

#d2 {
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    z-index: 15;
    left: 100px;
    top: 100px;
}
```

'position: absolute' should display heading on top of video. It didn't work. I added z-index of d2 to 15. But still it didn't help. I am unable to display the button on video. Can anyone please help me if there is any issue and how to fix.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`<video>` is not a self-closing element. [Info from MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/video)

```css
#d1 {
  font-family: 'Avenir', Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  color: #2c3e50;
  margin-top: 10px;
  width: 55%
}

#videoID {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 10;
}

#d2 {
  position: absolute;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: flex-start;
  height: 100%;
  z-index: 15;
  left: 100px;
}
```

```html
<div id="d1">
  <video id="videoID" src="http://clips.vorwaerts-gmbh.de/big_buck_bunny.mp4" type="video/mp4" autoplay></video>
  <div id="d2">
    <h1 id="h">I am heading</h1>
    <button type="button" id="play-pause" class="play">Play</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. I missed closing tag. One more related question. I need to display the button exactly at the center of the video. Is it possible to achive this through CSS alone or do I need to use Java script?

Comment: When I am playing on the web browser, video is taking whole space as I mentioned width and height s 100%. But when I open javascript console, video window size is getting reduced. The button should be always displayed on the center of the video.

Comment: Thanks. I haven't used flexbox. I need to read about flexbox :)

Comment: @kadina This is quite good https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/

Comment: Thanks for the link. I used in our code and it is working fine.